# Add lambda permission for a list of ARNs and add as a dependency of bucket notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a list of ARNs I need to add lambda permission AND consider as a dependency for the bucket notification but unsure how to tie both.

This is my variable:

```
variable "lambda_filters" {
  type = list(object({ lambda_function_arn : string, prefix : string, suffix : string }))
}
```

This is the permission and the notification:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket}"
     
  I HAVE A LIST AND NOT ONLY ONE ---> function_name = <MY ARN>
}
    
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = var.bucket
    
  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = var.lambda_filters
    iterator = it
    
    content {
      lambda_function_arn = it.value.lambda_function_arn
      events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
      filter_prefix       = it.value.prefix
      filter_suffix       = it.value.suffix
    }
    
    REFERENCE SOMEHOW HERE --> depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
  }
}
```

As you can see in `aws_s3_bucket_notification`, I want to add `depends_on` based on all buckets I have to add permission.

Lambda is being created in another module and ARN is the output of that:

```
output "lambda_arn" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda.qualified_arn
}
```

Module is being used like this:

```
module "s3_bucket_notifications" {
  source = "../bucket_notifications"
    
  lambda_filters = [
    {
      lambda_function_arn : module.my_lambda.lambda_arn,
      prefix : "blah/blah", suffix : ".zip"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I create lambda permissions for all ARNs inside that list and reference from bucket notification?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how there is a list of Lambda functions while you have only one output value defined?

Comment: @MarkoE part of the code :) it's the output of a module

Comment: So you will pass more than one Lambda function ARN and prefix when calling the `s3_bucket_notifications` module?

Comment: @MarkoE exactly! Just unsure how to tie that list with `aws_lambda_permission` resource

Comment: Ok, so for starters, you need an output in the Lambda module for the function name. The `aws_lambda_permission` is using the `function_name` attribute not ARN.

Comment: @MarkoE i can change that :) easy change actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is a bit of refactoring of a part of the code to make it easier to work with the rest of the code you have. I would start with redefining the `lambda_filters` variable in such a way it is a map instead of a list, as using it with `for_each` will be easier:

```
variable "lambda_filters" {
  type        = map(map(string))
  description = "(optional) describe your variable"

  default = {
    "lambda1" = {
      "lambda_function_arn" = "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:111122223333:rule"
      "prefix"              = "blah/blah"
      "suffix"              = ".zip"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when calling the module for bucket notification, you could try something like:

```
module "s3_bucket_notifications" {
  source = "../bucket_notifications"

  lambda_filters = {
    "${module.my_lambda.lambda_function_name}" = {
      "lambda_function_arn" = module.my_lambda.lambda_arn
      "prefix" = "blah/blah"
      "suffix" = ".zip"
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, for this to work, you would have to define an output value in the Lambda module, i.e., `module.my_lambda.lambda_function_name`.

The last part can be reconfigured to use `for_each` in the `aws_lambda_permission` resource:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  for_each      = var.lambda_filters
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket}"
  function_name = each.key
}
```

While the `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource can be rewritten like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = var.bucket

  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = var.lambda_filters
    content {
      lambda_function_arn = lambda_function.value.lambda_function_arn
      events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
      filter_prefix       = lambda_function.value.prefix
      filter_suffix       = lambda_function.value.suffix
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marko! Let me try that! The only "bad thing" is that I will keep seeing "Unresolved reference prefix " for all the values in the map. Might be a bit confusing for other devs

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the warning/error? Is this after testing the code from the answer?

Comment: Just Intellij showing as error as none of those values exist.

Comment: Changed to this format :) lambda_function.value["prefix"]

Comment: Yeah, both should work. :)

Comment: One Lambda can be configured with multiple prefixes and suffixes, something like this: type = map(list(object({ lambda_arn : string, prefix : string, suffix : string }))). Is there a way to adapt "bucket_notification" to work with a 2nd loop? Thanks Marko!

Comment: Just follow the same logic as when providing one lambda function.